# Replace the same value multiple if formatting a string?

Tags: python

I need just to replace the name of font as RSQFont if value 123 or Regular if not value ..
So I have this code ...

```
if 123.value:
    FontName='RSQFont'
else:
    FontName='Regular'

"""<screen backgroundColor="#16000000" name="AGC_Picon" position="210,130" size="800,470" title="Quick Signal Info" zPosition="1" flags="wfNoBorder">
    <widget source="Title" render="Label" font="%(key)s;23" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" position="0,0" size="350,30" transparent="1" />
    <widget source="global.CurrentTime" render="Label" position="545,0" size="250,30" font="%(key)s;23" valign="top" halign="left" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="ClockToText">Format:%d-%m-%Y   %H:%M:%S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,403" size="200,25" font="%(key)s; 20" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#fec000" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%F %p %Y %M %s</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,435" size="200,23" font="%(key)s; 18" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%c %l %h %m %g %b %e %S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget name="Satfinder" position="5,319" size="300,18" zPosition="1" font="%(key)s;17" halign="left" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#0000deff" transparent="1" />
</screen>""" % {'key': FontName,}
```

But I have got this error

```
 """ % {'key': FontName,}
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I tried different method but I can not solve it ...

I have tried

```
 .format(FontName)
```

instead of

```
{'key': FontName,}
```

And other things but nothing to help ...
and advice ?!!!

P.s: I cannot use %s code because some lines already have and use it with other python files as like this

```
<convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%F %p %Y %M %s</convert>
```

and

```
<convert type="ClockToText">Format:%d-%m-%Y   %H:%M:%S</convert>
```

Comment: why not use f-string or `str.format()`, instead of old-style string formatting or even template engine like `jinja2`?

Comment: Perhaps it's a posting problem, but the "code" in the first part of your question is invalid and doesn't make sense. Does it contain a triple-quoted string somewhere?

Comment: @burn .. Already I have try (""" % str.format(FontName)) but I got error (format requires a mapping) ...

Comment: @martineau .. You are right my question post I was added wrong .. I have edit it ... but in my python file correct with """ codes """" and same error !!!

Comment: Now it makes more sense. The problem is because the string contains `%` characters which Python's `%` string operator interprets. To work around it you would need to "escape" all the other `%` characters by doubling them (so the `%` string operator could turn them back into single characters). A simpler workaround would be to use the more modern `str.format()` method that uses `{` and `}` characters (as @buran suggested already).

Comment: Thank you ... This work with me now like this (font="{};23") and with (""".format(FontName, FontName, FontName, FontName, FontName)) ... But How can I make the code small ?! with only one (FontName) like this .format(FontName) Because the value is already the same and I have other code contains more that 20 {} ?!!!

Comment: Another alternative (that also uses `{` and `}` characters) would be to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) which were added in Python 3.6.

Comment: If you used `font="{0};23"` you would only have to pass `FontName` once.

Comment: @buran Your code also work as well as good .. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments - use f-string:

```
font_name='RSQFont'

html = f"""<screen backgroundColor="#16000000" name="AGC_Picon" position="210,130" size="800,470" title="Quick Signal Info" zPosition="1" flags="wfNoBorder">
    <widget source="Title" render="Label" font="{font_name};23" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" position="0,0" size="350,30" transparent="1" />
    <widget source="global.CurrentTime" render="Label" position="545,0" size="250,30" font="{font_name};23" valign="top" halign="left" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="ClockToText">Format:%d-%m-%Y   %H:%M:%S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,403" size="200,25" font="{font_name}; 20" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#fec000" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%F %p %Y %M %s</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,435" size="200,23" font="{font_name}; 18" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%c %l %h %m %g %b %e %S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget name="Satfinder" position="5,319" size="300,18" zPosition="1" font="{font_name};17" halign="left" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#0000deff" transparent="1" />
</screen>"""

print(html)
```

or `str.format()` method:

```
font_name='RSQFont'

html = """<screen backgroundColor="#16000000" name="AGC_Picon" position="210,130" size="800,470" title="Quick Signal Info" zPosition="1" flags="wfNoBorder">
    <widget source="Title" render="Label" font="{font};23" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" position="0,0" size="350,30" transparent="1" />
    <widget source="global.CurrentTime" render="Label" position="545,0" size="250,30" font="{font};23" valign="top" halign="left" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="ClockToText">Format:%d-%m-%Y   %H:%M:%S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,403" size="200,25" font="{font}; 20" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#fec000" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%F %p %Y %M %s</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget source="session.CurrentService" render="Label" position="599,435" size="200,23" font="{font}; 18" halign="center" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#00bbbbbb" transparent="1">
        <convert type="RaedQuickServName2">%c %l %h %m %g %b %e %S</convert>
    </widget>
    <widget name="Satfinder" position="5,319" size="300,18" zPosition="1" font="{font};17" halign="left" backgroundColor="#54111112" foregroundColor="#0000deff" transparent="1" />
</screen>""".format(font=font_name) # or .format(**{'font':font_name})
print(html)
```

You can also go for a more complex solution using template engine like `jinja2`, which is de-facto standard approach in web-development